# JavaScript How to format input data to a specific expression

Tags: javascript, plotly, expression

I have some data that I need to feed into Plotly.

The only format Plotly seems to accept is:

```
{x: ['bananas', 'apples'], y: [10, 15], name: 'fruits', type: 'bar'}
```

I have the data like so:

```
fruits = ['bananas', 'apples']
number = [10, 15]
```

but if I try to create the format using template literals, I can't get it right.

My code is:

```
expression = `{x: [${fruits}], y: [${number}], name: 'fruits', type: 'bar'}`
```

but my output is

```
"{x: [bananas,apples], y: [10,15], name: 'fruits', type: 'bar'}"
```

There are 2 problems:
The fruit strings are no longer in quotes, and there are quotes surrounding the whole expression.

Is there a way to format this expression correctly with my data?

Comment: You're creating strings where plotly is expecting arrays. Just don't use a template literal. `expression = {x: fruits, y: number, name: 'fruits', type: 'bar'}`.

Comment: template literals will always return a string. 
What is wrong with:

`expression = {x: fruits, y: number, name: 'fruits', type: 'bar'}` ??

Comment: I tried it without the template literal, but I get the error: unexpected token '{'

Comment: I see the problem. I was asking the wrong question. Thank you guys for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
  const fruits = ["bananas", "apples"];
  const number = [10, 15];
  const expression ={ x: fruits, y: number, name: "fruits", type: "bar" }
  console.log(expression);
```